# If I have two modular exponentiation equations, can I find the base?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Let $$m^5=7\quad (\operatorname{mod} 7769)$$ and $$m^7=252\quad(\operatorname{mod} 7769)$$

How can I find $m$?

Comment: Well, you can compute $m^2$ from these two, and then can compute $m$ from that.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate multiplicative inverses in modular arithmetic? There's sort of two steps to the solution - one is using inverses, the other is an algebraic manipulation that gives $m$ using powers and inverses of the two expressions.

Comment: Note that $7769 = 17 \cdot 457$ is the product of two primes.  I would begin by tackling the solution for $m$ mod $17$.  If that proves infeasible (no solutions), then you are done.  If it can be solved mod $17$, I would then try to solve it mod $457$.   Solving both parts can be combined to give overall solutions in the usual (Chinese Remainder Thm.) way.

Comment: $m^7/m^5=m^2=6^2$ perhaps $m=6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m = m^{\large 21} m^{\large -20}\! = (m^{\large 7})^{\large 3} (m^{\large 5})^{\large -4}\! = 252^{\large 3}\, 7^{\large -4} = 36^{\large 3} 7^{\large  3} 7^{\large -4}  = 42\cdot 7^{\large -1} = 6$